# How to use the Or conditional operator for two types of ext.strategy within Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

I'm using a crossover and cross under moving average trading approach on Trading View in pine script.  Currently my `exit.strategy` is based on a 3 ATR stop loss.  It is working fine.  I want to back test an approach that introduces the idea of a faster MA crossover exit if this happens before the stop loss is hit.  I am new but have read the manual and taken a beginner python course. I looked into if-else and Or operators but I am presented with an error message.

This is the code (abbreviated to try and keep this short as possible)

#Trading conditions
`long = crossover(fastSMA, slowSMA)`
`short = crossunder(fastSMA, slowSMA)`
`exitLongquick = crossunder(exitSMA, slowSMA)`
`exitShortquick = crossover(exitSMA, slowSMA)`
`stopLossLong = low - atrValue*stopOffset`
`stopLossShort = high + atrValue*stopOffset`

Command to execute long trade entry and exits

```
if (long)
strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, PosSizeUnits) 

strategy.exit("exit", "long", stop=stopLossLong) or ("exit", "long", 
stop=exitLongquick)
```

Command to execute short trades

```
if (short)
strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, PosSizeUnits) 

strategy.exit("exit", "short", stop=exitShortquick) or ("exit", "long", 
stop=exitShortquick)
```

In both cases long and short it is the `strategy.exit` line where i get the error message "Mismatched input ',' expecting ')'."

If Conditional statements are the answer any help how to do that properly would be appreciated or any other suggestions otherwise also welcome.

I've tried various combinations of parenthesis and also tried if-else statements but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't double list the function's argument with an `or` operator.
If you would like the strategy to exit at `stopLossLong` level - include it in the `stop=` argument, however `exitLongquick` is not suitable for `stop=` argument, as it is a boolean value, and the argument requires a specific price. You can use the `strategy.close()` function under the `exitLongquick` local scope, as is shown in the example below:

```
if (long)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, PosSizeUnits) 

strategy.exit("exit", "long", stop=stopLossLong) 

if exitLongquick
    strategy.close("long")
```

Comment: Thanks e2e4 that's so helpful, it makes so much sense now i see i was trying to match a numerical function with a logical value! Thanks for the explanation, i tested your suggestion and it works great. Tx much.